# Life of Fragment inside TabHost

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost, android-lifecycle, fragmenttransaction

I am confused about moving between Fragments in a TabHost. I have following TabHost inside Activity:

```
    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
            R.id.layout_main_tab_content);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(FragmentA.TAG)
            .setIndicator("first"), FragmentA.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(
            tabHost.newTabSpec(FragmentB.TAG).setIndicator(
                    "second"), FragmentB.class, null);
```

If the tab in changed what exactly happens? What happens to the previous Fragment and the changed one? What is the transaction? Add/remove or replace?

Is there any way I can get (find) the Fragment from initialized tab? And how about restoring the previous fragment when I return to the tab (can I add the transaction to the backstack)?

Comment: did you get any idea on this topic, I am working on an Android app and facing the same issue with fragments' lifecycle changes inside a tabhost. Thank you.